# how to access specific data from JsonResponse

Tags: json

Supposing I have this return value

```
return JsonResponse( { 'message' : 'success', 'id' : newProductType.id }, safe = False )
```

and I have this function on success

```
.then( function( rs ){
      alert(rs.id)
```

Problem is, it alerts an undefined value. How do I access the id field in that object? Sorry, maybe its a very simple problem but Im a newbie so bear with me.

Comment: May be your response is `JSON String` instead of `JSON Object`. first try to convert it into JSON Object by using `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @Rohit Thanks. Already solved it though. maybe it has something to do with the library im using. I am using axios to execute my database calls and so, I accessed the data using "rs.data.id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

> **rs.new_id**

Because your response haven't id field.

Comment: my bad. pasted the wrong one. already changed that before. still getting undefine.